# Test Java Application in Different Locale

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have a product I built in the US. A friend in Poland was testing it today and the localized number formatting created some exceptions.

I would like to simulate running my program in Poland or Germany so that I can recreate those errors before I fix them. I thought it was as simple as setting the Locale, but every attempt seems to have no effect. I have called Locale.setDefault, and passed in -Duser.language=de_DE as VM args. But the numbers are always formatted in the US format (i.e. 1,000.00). But my friend loads the app and he see's 1.000,0.

Does anyone know how I can test my java application in Germany or Poland locale so I can see this formatting by default?

Comment: Can you please let us know more about your app's tech stack ? Is it a web app, desktop or mobile app ?  A random thought - Did you try just with -Duser.language=de ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, I set the locale information through `control panel -> region and language` (note that this is on `Windows`).

Or if you want to set it via JVM arguments, I think it should be something like this.

```
-Duser.language=de
-Duser.country=DE
```

you can check [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/locale-140624.html) for more information.

Comment: Bah - that did it. Thanks. Don't know where I got that other setting from.